# dragon curve with L system using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, l-systems

I want to compute dragon curve till n = 10 in java with L system using recursion. For example,

```
Replace all F characters with F-H
Replace all H characters with F+H

dragon(0) = F-H (this is the input)
dragon(1) = F-H-F+H
dragon(2) = F-H-F+H-F-H+F+H
...
dragon(10) = ?
```

How can I accomplish the same in java using recursion? I'm only interested in knowing the recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

In recursive approach such "replace" problem statements usually can be implemented as recursive calls.

So let's create two functions - `F()` and `H()` each of them will return `"F"` or `"H"` when desired curve depth is reached, or `F(...) + "-" + H(...)` or `F(...) + "+" + H(...)` if further expansion is needed.

```
private String F(int depth) {
  if (depth == 0) {
    return "F";
  } else {
    return F(depth - 1) + "-" + H(depth - 1);
  }
}

private String H(int depth) {
  if (depth == 0) {
    return "H";
  } else {
    return F(depth - 1) + "+" + H(depth - 1);
  }
}

public String dragon(int depth) {
  return F(depth + 1);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZGxbsJAEER7f8XI1VmWLUiL3CHLDRVllOKCD@eIOaO7taMo8rc7hlsMChSQZovZ0dvR7E52MtmVn8NwaN9rvcGmls5hJbXBTwCw6kjStFxaWTV@PRqs7iQprMlqUyEX2hBKdaCPiB2A3kKcJGQZZhcdsIpaaxDm4YK1Hqp26taSMyHBPEKMMAnHWVyJEyDw81664n/piqfTxY@l8@VyuPJU672Ef47EE@9I62@@1DW6xH78oPDk1zdIW7kzj9/nzyGDUV@sCcauvx2pfdq0lI4FGqqN8O6UM75EjzrnM2/tg34YfgE)